# SQL Server : connect two results with specific row

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table of users and a table of their contracts. I have two selects. The first one, which selects all from users table and second one, which selects only new users (from another user table) for "today". I need to connect those two results, but there's a problem.

Each user had "rownumber" column, it depends by count of contracts for each user (each user can have 1 or more contracts). I need to get new rownumber for new row. See example

The first select returns:

```
user_id | contract_id | rownumber
1         456           1
1         457           2
1         699           3
```

The second select selects new rows for those users:

```
user_id | contract_id
1         1024
1       | 1079
```

And I need to connect those results to get this end result:

```
user_id | contract_id | rownumber
 1         456           1
 1         457           2
 1         699           3
 1         1024          4
 1         1079          5
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Start with a UNION ALL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
;with cte
as
(
select 
user_id,contractid from table1
union all
select 
user_id,contractid from table2
)
select *,row_number() over (partition by user_id order by contractid ) from cte
```

Comment: `partition by user_id` I guess.

Comment: @Serg:Thanks,missed it

Answer (score 0):

```
select USER_ID, CONTRACT_ID,ROWNUMBER
from TABLE1 
union all
select USER_ID, CONTRACT_ID,rownum+num
from TABLE2,(select max(ROWNUMBER) as num
from TABLE1);
```

**union all** will display duplicate datas also. If you don't want duplicate records then replace **union all** by **union**